# Disable Chrome reading list only in some profiles?

Tags: google-chrome

Disabling the Chrome Reading List via chrome://flags disables the feature for all Chrome profiles using the PC. Is there a way to disable the Reading List in just some profiles?

Comment: I think you can't set flags for a specific profile of chrome